# Aurelia - Property modal does not exist on type ElementFinder

Tags: typescript, aurelia

aurelia.json under dependencies

```
"jquery",
      {
        "name": "bootstrap",
        "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
        "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
        "deps": ["jquery"],
        "exports": "$",
        "resources": [
          "css/bootstrap.css"
        ]
      }
```

add.ts

```
import "bootstrap";

export class Add{     
}

$('.modal').modal(); // .modal() has squiggly line.
```

add.html

```
<template>
    <h1>partners</h1>

    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure you want to delete?
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

When I run "au run --watch", i get...
src\partner\add.ts(19,13): error TS2339: Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'.
[10:11:25] gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] Error: src\partner\add.ts(19,13): error TS2339: Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'.

Answer (score 0):

ElementFinder is a return type from $('.modal'). It's a Protractor type, looks like your jquery global $ was overriden by protractor $ (http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$)